# How to access an annotation value (JUnit 4 -> JUnit 5)

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit5, test-runner

I am trying to port a project from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5. The project includes a custom runner that has a listener that detects whether a test has a certain annotation (`@GradedTest`) and accesses the annotation's key-value pairs. For example, it would be able to access the values associated with `name` and `points` in this code:

```
@Test
@GradedTest(name = "greet() test", points = "1")
public void defaultGreeting() {
    assertEquals(GREETING, unit.greet());
}
```

The existing JUnit 4 code has a [listener](https://github.com/tkutcher/jgrade/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/github/tkutcher/jgrade/gradedtest/GradedTestListener.java) that extends `RunListener` and [overrides](https://github.com/tkutcher/jgrade/blob/6049a0acfb17d829fb61488f9763913f3d7f65d7/src/main/java/com/github/tkutcher/jgrade/gradedtest/GradedTestListener.java#L81) `testStarted()`:

```
@Override
public void testStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
    super.testStarted(description);

    this.currentGradedTestResult = null;

    GradedTest gradedTestAnnotation = description.getAnnotation(GradedTest.class);
    if (gradedTestAnnotation != null) {
        this.currentGradedTestResult =  new GradedTestResult(
                gradedTestAnnotation.name(),
                gradedTestAnnotation.number(),
                gradedTestAnnotation.points(),
                gradedTestAnnotation.visibility()
        );
    }
}
```

Note that this makes use of [`Description.getAnnotation()`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/runner/Description.html#getAnnotation(java.lang.Class)).

I am trying to switch to the [JUnit Platform Launcher API](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api). I can use a [`LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.1.1/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/core/LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.html) to select the tests I want to run, and I can create listeners that extend [`SummaryGeneratingListener`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/listeners/SummaryGeneratingListener.html) and override [`executionStarted(TestIdentifier testIdentifier)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/listeners/SummaryGeneratingListener.html#executionStarted-org.junit.platform.launcher.TestIdentifier-). I see no way, however, to get an annotation and its values from a [`TestIdentifier`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/TestIdentifier.html).

What is the JUnit 5 equivalent of [`Description.getAnnotation()`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/runner/Description.html#getAnnotation(java.lang.Class)) or the new way of getting a test annotation's values?

Comment: Can you elaborate the purpose of GradedTestResult? What do you want to do with it after or during the test run? I have an inkling that the Launcher API is not really what you need, but the purpose of the annotation is not clear to me.

Comment: @johanneslink `GradedTestResult` collects information about each annotated test, including its name, number of points, and whether it passed. This is used to create a report. It is used for autograding student code submissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a way to get annotations, but I do not know how robust it is. This is how I overrode `SummaryGeneratingListener.executionStarted(TestIdentifier identifier)`:

```
@Override
public void executionStarted(TestIdentifier identifier) {
    super.executionStarted(identifier);
    this.currentGradedTestResult = null;

    // Check if this is an atomic test, not a container.
    if (identifier.isTest()) {
        // Check if the test's source is provided.
        TestSource source = identifier.getSource().orElse(null);
        // If so, and if it's a MethodSource, get and use the annotation if present.
        if (source != null && source instanceof MethodSource) {
            GradedTest gradedTestAnnotation = ((MethodSource) source).getJavaMethod().getAnnotation(GradedTest.class);
            if (gradedTestAnnotation != null) {
                this.currentGradedTestResult = new GradedTestResult(
                        gradedTestAnnotation.name(),
                        gradedTestAnnotation.number(),
                        gradedTestAnnotation.points(),
                        gradedTestAnnotation.visibility()
                );

                this.currentGradedTestResult.setScore(gradedTestAnnotation.points());
            }
        }
    }

    this.testOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(this.testOutput));
}
```

The weak link is [`TestIdentifier.getSource()`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.2/api/org.junit.platform.launcher/org/junit/platform/launcher/TestIdentifier.html#getSource()). The documentation says it gets "the source of the represented test or container, *if available*." It works for my tests, but I don't know under what circumstances the source is (not) available.

Comment: Have a look JUnit‘s AnnotationSupport class. It could simplify your code a bit.

Comment: @johanneslink Thanks very much, although it's not clear to me how that would simplify the code. I still want to execute unannotated methods, just not run the conditional code. In order to get the annotation, I'd need the class, which would require an instance variable or extracting it from the `identifier`. Do you think that would be more robust than relying on `getSource()`?

Comment: getSource() is the right way to get at the test class and method. Using AnnotationSupport allows you to treat annotations the same way JUnit does, including inheritance and meta annotations - if you want that.